# download apk file from given url to server using php

Tags: php, linux, curl, download

I want to download apk file from url on remote server I have used

```
set_time_limit(0);
$file1 = fopen($destinationDir.$fileName, "w");
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_FILE           => $file1,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 1000,
CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT\
5.0)' ]);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
if($response === false) {
throw new \Exception('Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl));
}
```

But sometimes when the file gets downloaded, it is 0kb file and sometimes the file size 40  kb whereas the original file size 2 MB. When I go to the given link through browser it get downloaded but not using php. Please suggest me any alternative or correction in it.
P.S I am a beginner and I require this in my college project. Thank you in advance

Comment: Try increasing your timeout. 1s might be too short.

Comment: @cherryDT it's not working I increased the timeout

Comment: @the 4242nd Doctor Thank u so much for your corrections

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to download file from url.

You just pass your url and path to where you want to download.

```
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://example.com");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

 // the following lines write the contents to a file in the same directory 
 (provided permissions etc)
 $output_filename = "folderame/filename";
 $fp = fopen($output_filename, 'w');
 fwrite($fp, $result);
 fclose($fp);
}
```

It's work fine for me.